# .NET user control for use in a web browser and prevent design time use

Tags: .net, com, activex

I created a .NET user control that will be installed on a user's pc via cab file. the cab will be signed with my company name and will register the .net component on the user's machine.

I would like to make sure that users do not take my .net binaries that are on their pc and use them at design time in 'ANY' IDE ..

With ActiveX controls I could achieve that by simply using a .lic file..

Can I implement the same with a .NET control Registered as COM ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works the exact same way in .NET.  Start [reading here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe8b1eh9.aspx).